# Class and function with the same name

Tags: python, namespaces

Have a module as sample.py with the below code:

```
def ABC():
    print('Called!')


class ABC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('Class Called')
```

Now when i import the module in shell and invoke ABC the class gets called and i know that based on the print statement that is seen on the shell. I thought this should be a naming conflict as both the function and the class are in the global namespace with the same name. How is this mechanism working?

Comment: When you give the class the name `ABC`, that name is no longer associated with the function. Just the same as reassigning a variable.

Comment: In practice, this should never happen. names for functions would not be appropriate for names of a class, and if two functions are the same name then they probably do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

The function and the class can't be "in the global namespace with the same name", as otherwise it would be impossible to tell them apart. The function is defined with the identifier ABC, then the class is defined with the same identifier ABC, overwriting it. This can be seen more clearly in the interactive Python interpreter:

```
>>> def ABC():
...     pass
... 
>>> type(ABC)
<class 'function'>
>>> class ABC(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             pass
... 
>>> type(ABC)
<class 'type'>
```

This shows that after the function definition, ABC is of the type 'function', but after the class definition, it is of the type 'type' (which is the case for classes). In Python, as everything is an object (functions and classes included), names (like ABC) can be overridden like this without throwing errors. This is no different to:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>
>>> a = "Mug"
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>
```

Of course, this can cause problems when it's not intentional; the idea of namespaces is used to divide up the scope of names so identical names don't override each other like this. For example, dividing your code up into modules provides separate namespaces within each module.

Right now, you might be better off naming your class and function differently so the names don't collide and overwrite each other like this.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @jon , that explanation helps.